# Difference between .next and .succ in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between `Fixnum` methods `.next` and `.succ` in Ruby?
It seems it works identically:

```
 1.next
 => 2
 1.succ
 => 2
```

If there is any difference why there is two method which do the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are equivalent. `Fixnum#succ` is just an synonym for `Fixnum#next`.

They even share the same block in [the reference manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-succ).

Comment: But why? There is any historical reason why there is redundant method in ruby? IMO this redundance doesn't fit to such elegant and simply language as ruby.

Comment: Because it's easy to remember? There are many others in different classes / modules: `map` and `collect`; `include?` and `has_key`; `size` and `length`, `format` and `sprintf` ...

Comment: @Kefas You are misunderstanding Ruby. Ruby follows Perl's motto: there is more than one way to do it, and it tries to be capable with people experienced in other languages. Ruby has many aliases.